# Cond statement causing slime to crash

Tags: lisp

The first part of my function is a simple cond statement. It works perfectly by itself but when the rest of the function is added it causes an unexpected error.

Problems occure when passing:
(expo 2 0)
(expo 2 1)
The function works perfectly for any other positive value of n.

```
(defun expo (b n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 1)
        ((= n 1) b))
  (defparameter m (* b b))
  (defun expo_iter (a b)
    (cond ((= a n) b)
          ((= (+ a 1) n) (* b (sqrt m)))
          ((expo_iter (+ a 2) (* b m)))))
  (expo_iter 2 m)
```

When (expo 2 0) 'lisp connection lost unexpectedly, connection broken by remote peer.' Never had this error before, any ideas?

Comment: there is a closing parenthesis missing. The code won't work at all.

Answer (score 3):

There are many things wrong with this function.

- The initial `cond` is almost certainly malformed since it does nothing at all.  Probably it should.
- There's a missing close paren which I assume is a cut & paste error.
- Don't use `defparameter` (or `defvar`, or `defconstant`) other than at toplevel unless you *really* know what you are doing.  Instead use `let`.
- Don't use `defun` other than at toplevel unless you *really* know what you are doing.  Instead use `labels` (or `flet`).
- the local function has an argument with the same name as one of the arguments to the the global function which is confusing (although I often do that too, this says something bad about my programs, not that it is OK).

The use of non-toplevel `defun` &c makes it look as if it has been translated, badly, from Scheme perhaps?  The Scheme equivalent would be less atrocious *but still would fail to terminate*.

Then if you actually *think* about what the function does you will see why it fails to terminate, and will either cause a stack overflow very quickly in if tail calls are not eliminated, or will eventually die through memory exhaustion because of bignum consing if they are.  Just think about what the base case of the recursion is.  What should the junk `cond` be doing?